Unable to load template file 'modules/Vtiger/uitypes/Barcode.tpl'
Everything was working fine when running 6.5 until i migrated from 6.5 to 7.0.1.
I have this error: Unable to load template file modules/Vtiger/uitypes/Barcode.tpl in modules/Vtiger/partials/EditViewContents.tpl when I try to add a new asset. I can see the list of all assets but when I click the 'Add' button, i get the error popup.
I know the error means that the page is trying to load the Barcode.tpl from the directory but it isn't present in modules/Vtiger/uitypes/. But my problem here is the file isn't in this directory if you go by vtiger_root_dir/modules/vtiger/uitypes. The file is in Vtiger_root_dir/layouts/vlayout/modules/vtiger/uitypes/Barcode.tpl.
If i copy the files from Vtiger_root_dir/layouts/vlayout/modules/vtiger/uitypes/ to  vtiger_root_dir/modules/vtiger/uitypes the error disappears but a new one emgerges which is

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Vtiger_Record_Model::getBarcodeDetails() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\transport\test\templates_c\v7\bd2acef9c2f2821ff4231451da4831b3668c8254.file.BarcodeDetailView.tpl.php on line 30

And the barcode function doesn't still work. The Barcode function triggers when  Bin numbers are inputted and immediately prints a barcode on the Barcode field.
Note: I am currently running the migrated 7.0.1 and on php 5.6. If i switch to php 7.2, i get the following error:

Fatal error: The file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\transport\modules\RelatedListviewEdits\models\Module.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.5 and cannot run under PHP 7.1 or later. Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1. in Unknown on line 0.

This is gor a extensions. Not just the RelatedListViewEdits extension.

"until i migrated from 6.5 to 7.0.1." - phew, 7.0.1 is nearly seven years old. Are oyu sure you've checked everything from their list of steps for an upgrade? Also, keep in mind that PHP 7 and also PHP 5 are horribly outdated and out of support since years

Unfortunately, vtiger has no way to upgrade straight to version 8.1 without going from one version to another. Its a tedious task. Yes, I have checked everything on the steps to migrate. This is like the 100th time i am trying this. Too many errors i meet and i keep resolving till i got here.
